# using nextSibling function in dictionary

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping

I am scraping some data from a list of websites stored in a CSV called websites.csv. scrapper works however I am running into an issue. When I output the data into the scraped_data.csv tag1 and tag2 have the same data this is because both tags share the same attribute in html. pictured below The columns in the csv are as such
[tag1] = 1 available, [tag2] = 1 available
the result I am looking for is
[tag1] = 1 available, [tag2] = 4/11/2019
I have done some research and think that using the nextSibling function could be the solution here however I am a bit puzzled about how to add it to my code to achieve the desired results and help would be appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

'''

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/websites.csv', usecols=['website'], 
delimiter=',')
url = df['website']

df.dropna(subset=['website'])


data = []

df.to_csv(header=True, index=False, path_or_buf='/Users/Desktop/scraped_data.csv')

print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     website = row['website']
     response = requests.get(website)
     content = response.text

     

     soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
     result = soup.find('div',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_support-card__fK7N2')
     

     tag1 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_field-text__GtuGd')
     tag2 = soup.find('div',class_ = 'ant-col KeyStatisticsCard_field-info__gYdfV')
     tag3 = soup.find('a',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')
     tag4 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')
     tag5 = soup.find('a', href = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')



d = {
'tag1':tag1.text if tag1 else None,
'tag2':tag2.text if tag2 else None,
'tag3':tag3.text if tag3 else None,
'tag4':tag4.text if tag4 else None,
'tag5':tag5.text if tag5 else None } 

data.append(d)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)
```

'''

Comment: `soup.select_one('div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date") + div')`

Comment: Should I add this to my dictionary?

Comment: Does tag 2 always follow text of onboarded  date? i.e. next div?

Comment: Yes it does as the next 'div'

Comment: Does `tag2 = soup.select_one('div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date")`  work then?

Comment: getting SyntaxError- EOL error i think the quotes in the string are messed up

Comment: `tag2 = soup.select_one('div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date") + div')` . Sorry, missed the 2nd line when copying from first comment.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! I have one final request could you break it down for me just for educational purposes. why use select_one instead of find? and this part:
('div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date") + div')

I understand each value but am unsure how it all ties together. Thank you again!!!

Comment: I've expanded into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the whole thing with a CSS selector list. In the following we have:

div element with class attribute that contains (*) the string *KeyStatisticsCard*

```
div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]
```

And that also contains the text *Onboarded Date* in the node

```
:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date")
```

Because these are immediately adjacent it means apply these matchings as AND

```
div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date")
```

We then want to move to the adjacent (following) div node at the same level in the DOM. We can do that using an adjacent sibling combinator (+).

Putting that all together we can target the desired tag2 node as follows:

```
tag2 = soup.select_one('div[class*=KeyStatisticsCard]:-soup-contains("Onboarded Date") + div')
```

select_one ensures only the first node matching the pattern specified by the CSS selector list is returned.

You can read more about CSS selectors and combinators on MDN e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

You can practice CSS selectors in a variety of places including in the elements tab of your browser. I like the following resource as an intro: https://flukeout.github.io/

As to why I used a CSS selector list, because it has nice versatile and easy to read syntax.